# Polymorphic model binding / Complex Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding, asp.net-core-3.1

I have problem in model binding. When I submit form it returns me id=0 and device is null? and  how to solve it. My goal is to add new device, and choose device type from view by selector. if user selects smartphone it has to add fields for smartphone. I don't want to save device type in base class as Kind variable. Thanks in advance(sorry for english)

controller->

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    MainCont mainCont = new MainCont();
    return View(mainCont);
}
```

index.cshtml ->

```
@model MainCont
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<form action="home/create" method="post">
    @Html.Partial("example",Model.Device)
    <button type="submit">გაგზავნა</button>
</form>
```

example.cshtml ->

```
@model SmartPhone
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.imei)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.screensize)
```

Device Model ->

```
public abstract class Device : Object
{
}
```

LaptopModel ->

```
public class Laptop : Device
{
    public string CPU { get; set; }
    public string GPu { get; set; }
}
```

MainCont ->

```
public class MainCont
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

SmartphoneModel ->

```
public class SmartPhone : Device
{
    public string screensize { get; set; }
    public string imei { get; set; }
}
```

model binder ->

```
using Bind.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bind
{
    public class DeviceModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private Dictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)> binders;

        public DeviceModelBinder(Dictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)> binders)
        {
            this.binders = binders;
        }

        public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
           
            IModelBinder modelBinder;
            ModelMetadata modelMetadata;
            if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(Laptop))
            {
                (modelMetadata, modelBinder) = binders[typeof(Laptop)];
            }
            else if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(SmartPhone))
            {
                (modelMetadata, modelBinder) = binders[typeof(SmartPhone)];
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
                return;
            }

            var newBindingContext = DefaultModelBindingContext.CreateBindingContext(
                bindingContext.ActionContext,
                bindingContext.ValueProvider,
                modelMetadata,
                bindingInfo: null,
                bindingContext.ModelName);

            await modelBinder.BindModelAsync(newBindingContext);
            bindingContext.Result = newBindingContext.Result;

            if (newBindingContext.Result.IsModelSet)
            {
                // Setting the ValidationState ensures properties on derived types are correctly 
                bindingContext.ValidationState[newBindingContext.Result] = new ValidationStateEntry
                {
                    Metadata = modelMetadata,
                };
            }
        }

    }
}
```

binderprovider ->

```
using Bind.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bind
{
    public class DeviceModelBinderProvider: IModelBinderProvider
    {
        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context.Metadata.ModelType != typeof(Device))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var subclasses = new[] { typeof(Laptop), typeof(SmartPhone), };

            var binders = new Dictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)>();
            foreach (var type in subclasses)
            {
                var modelMetadata = context.MetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(type);
                binders[type] = (modelMetadata, context.CreateBinder(modelMetadata));
            }

            return new DeviceModelBinder(binders);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo:

Index.cshtml(when select SmartPhone,use example.cshtml,when select Laptop,use example1.cshtml):

```
@model MainCont
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

    <form asp-action="create" asp-controller="home" method="post">
        <select id="select" name="select">
            <option value="SmartPhone">SmartPhone </option>
            <option value="Laptop">Laptop  </option>
        </select>
        <div id="sample"></div>
        <button type="submit">გაგზავნა</button>
    </form>
@section scripts{ 
<script>
    $(function () {
        GetPartialView();
    })
    $("#select").change(function () {
        GetPartialView();
    })
    function GetPartialView() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Test1/ReturnExample",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                select: $("#select").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#sample').html(data);
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
}
```

example.cshtml:

```
@model SmartPhone
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.imei)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.screensize)
```

example1.cshtml:

```
@model Laptop
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CPU)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GPu)
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new MainCont());
        }
        public IActionResult ReturnExample(string select)
        {
            if (select == "SmartPhone")
            {
                return PartialView("~/Views/Test1/example.cshtml", new SmartPhone());
            }
            else {
                return PartialView("~/Views/Test1/example1.cshtml", new Laptop());
            }
            
        }
```

Create Action in Home Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([ModelBinder(typeof(DataBinder))]MainCont mainCont) {
            return Ok();
        }
```

DataBinder:

```
public class DataBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }
            var model1 = new MainCont();

            var select = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("select").FirstValue;
            if (select == "SmartPhone")
            {
                var model2 = new SmartPhone();
                model2.screensize = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("screensize").FirstValue;
                model2.imei = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("imei").FirstValue;
                model1.Device = model2;
            }
            else if (select == "Laptop")
            {
                var model2 = new Laptop();
                model2.CPU = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("CPU").FirstValue;
                model2.GPu = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("GPu").FirstValue;
                model1.Device = model2;
            }

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model1);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: If it is helpful,can you mark it as answer?Thank you.

Comment: and also do you know how to bind complex models? imagine cpu is object, that contains another properties, that are not string, and what if this properties get values from enum?

Comment: I think you can open a new case to tell more about your new question.Such as your CPU model.and in your view you how to bind CPU data.Custom Model Binder needs to be modified according to your model and the data you pass.

Comment: `scheduleDebtGenerator.PaymentInterval.Type = (PaymentIntervalType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PaymentIntervalType), bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("PaymentInterval.Type").FirstValue);
                    scheduleDebtGenerator.PaymentInterval.Value = Decimal.Parse(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("PaymentInterval.Value").FirstValue);`

Comment: is it correct way? Does it need tryparse with error messages? or only parse.

Comment: scheduleDebtGenerator is like smartphone and PaymentInterval is like cpu with type and value props.

Comment: [see more details](http://wiki.altasoft.ge/KA/index.php?title=LAPI_%E1%83%95%E1%83%94%E1%83%91_%E1%83%A1%E1%83%94%E1%83%A0%E1%83%95%E1%83%98%E1%83%A1%E1%83%98#CashflowScheduler)

Comment: I think you'd better open a new case,and share it with English.